# Automatically Call Number On Load

Tags: android, eclipse

I've made a small app for myself but seem to have a problem. Basically I'm looking to make an app that checks my credit when I select it.

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       phoneCall();
    }

    private void phoneCall()
    {
     String phoneCallUri = "tel:*#100#";
     Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
     phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));
     startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
    }
```

I'm using some recycled code I found on the internet. I was able to get it to work when I called the method with an onclick and was using my mobile number. I think the problem is the special characters but I'm not sure. I have the call permission in my manifest, I basically took most of the code from my working app and altered it. Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post the logcat and show us the manifest file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL, Uri.parse("tel:" + "Your Phone_number"));
startActivity(intent);
```

And use this Permission

```
android.permission.CALL_PHONE
```

Comment: This worked perfect, thank you. I figured it was an issue with the string and putting "tel: " + phoneCallUri worked, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

It is the '#' character that blocks it. It is a special character which needs to be escaped.

You can refer to this thread : https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/az7OnaempKY

```
String encodedHash = Uri.encode("#"); 
String phoneCallUri = "tel:"+ "*"+encodedHash+"100"+ encodedHash;

Intent phoneCallIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
phoneCallIntent.setData(Uri.parse(phoneCallUri));

startActivity(phoneCallIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        String phoneCallUri = "*#100#";
        Intent dial = new Intent();
        dial.setAction("android.intent.action.DIAL");
        dial.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phoneCallUri));
        startActivity(dial);

  }

}
```